# Initial segment symbol

Tags: symbols

What is the command for this [image]

symbol? It should be easily googlable, but I do not know the name and googling 'initial segment symbol latex' does not give any results.

Comment: It is     `\prec`. The other direction is `\succ`.

Answer (score 0):

In the guide of the list of the many symbol used in `LaTeX`  http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf, as suggested by the very talented users @Werner and @Bernard, the symbol of the image is `\prec` (see the page 48 - Table 88: Binary Relations).

Here there is a possible MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\prec$
\end{document}
```

PS: no vote please. Just to help the user with a MWE.