# Shift brackets up for fraction in superscript

Tags: brackets, superscripts

The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
E \left[ e^{\frac{\sigma^2 \lambda^2}{2}} \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

produces brackets that  symmetric(-ish) around the x-height, so they include the exponent properly, but they look way too low on the bottom. Is there a way to correct this?

[image: asymmetrical-looking braces around large superscript.]

Please don't suggest to use exp() instead.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/399482/134574

Comment: It may be related but it's not a duplicate. The other question is about containing a vertically-unbalanced fraction within parentheses. Mine is about a superscript. They might have the same solution, but they aren't the same problem.

Comment: That's why I didn't vote to _close_ your question as duplicate, but just pointed you to something that might be useful :-) [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516332/134574) (and countless many others) was closed as duplicate of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/134574). The questions are completely different but the solution is the same, so I see no problem.

Comment: Doesn't `\fixit{[}{e^{\frac{\sigma^2 \lambda^2}{2}}}{]}` with `\fixit` from [@PhelypeOleinik's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399533/194703) solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

To make the math expression look better, I would *not* bother with either shifting up the large square brackets or with pulling down the exponent term. Instead, I would use inline-fraction notation to reduce the needlessly large vertical size of the exponent term; this adjustment will also let you use less-prominent square brackets. And, it will make the exponent term *easier to read*, since TeX will be in script-style instead of in scriptscript-style when it processes the letters `\sigma` and `\lambda` in the exponent.

By the way, assuming that "E" denotes the (unconditional) expectations operator, I would typeset the letter in the upright font shape.

Incidentally, I don't get your apparent aversion to `\exp` notation. It was created for sound typographic reasons.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\DeclareMathOperator" macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % expectations operator
\begin{document}
\[
E \left[ e^{\frac{\sigma^2 \lambda^2}{2}} \right] 
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\E \bigl[ e^{\sigma^2 \lambda^2/2} \bigr] 
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\E [ \exp(\sigma^2 \lambda^2/2) ]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the inline fraction looks decent. I use `\mathbb{E}` (via a macro) in papers but I was being lazy for this question. I am fine with `\exp`, I just get annoyed when stack exchange people assume every single question is an "XY problem".